# For Struts 2(2.5.14) which Spring Version will be Compatible

Tags: spring, struts2, struts, struts-config

I'm migrating Struts 1 to Struts 2. In Struts 1, Spring 1.1.2 is used for Dependent Injection, AOP.

Same Way which version of Spring is compatible with Struts 2 (2.5.14)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Maven Struts 2.5.x will use Spring 4.1.6. This notes is from the documentation http://struts.apache.org/getting-started/spring.html

> The current version (2.5.10.1) of the Struts 2 Spring plugin has transitive dependencies to the Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE version.